# Recommendation for type of switch

Tags: switches, audio, instrumentation-amplifier

What type of switch would you recommend for the diagram below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 4PDT switch should do it, assuming you want to switch both leads and not have a common between the amps.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOIT8f.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the position shown, AMP 1 is connected to the speaker and AMP 2 is connected to the dummy load, in the other position they would be swapped. If you can't find a suitable switch and you have a power source available you could use an SPST switch and one or more relays to get the number of contacts you need.

If you can make one lead common (this would depend on the amplifiers used) you could use a DPDT. Some amps might not take kindly to having their outputs connected to another amp like this, so due caution is advised.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffqd4r.png)</sup>

If you can't find a suitable switch and you have a power source available you could use an SPST switch and one or more relays to get the number of contacts you need.